# How to create snapshot with UEFI firmware on virt-manager?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, virt-manager

I am using `qemu` v2.11.1 and `libvirt` 4.0.0 - both are latest stable for Ubuntu 18.04. The guest is Windows 10 running on Tianocore UEFI firmware. When I tried to take a snapshot on `virt-manager`, it thew an error and looks like it does not allow **internal** snapshots to be created on UEFI firmware.

[image]

I do not really concern about having a chain of **external** snapshots, as long as I can use UEFI firmware. However, `virt-manager` shows no option to choose between internal and external snapshot styles in the snapshot management tab.

Is there any way to do that? Or I must give up on `virt-manager` go back to command line?

Comment: (apologies, I've deleted my answer. I don't snapshot my VMs in this setup, and in fairness I have none running on UEFI but I can give it a spin)

Comment: libvirt does not support internal snapshot for pflash. You can only do external flash (--disk-only)

Comment: possibly there is an option to snapshot the qcow2 with the qemu shell directly,  tldr https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/Snapshots#Snapshot_command_flow

Comment: What @Wang says: https://listman.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2017-March/msg01087.html

Comment: UEFI snapshots are not yet supported: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1881850

Comment: copy xml file, copy pflash vars, do qemu-img snapshot ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error creating snapshot: Operation not supported: internal snapshots of a VM with pflash based firmware are not supported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/663372/error-creating-snapshot-operation-not-supported-internal-snapshots-of-a-vm-wit)

Comment: @robertspierre 2 years have passed and I don't really care about `virt-manager` anymore. The reason `virt-manager` refuses to do a snapshot on a machine with pflash devices is probably it doesn't like to manage multiple snapshots across multiple devices.

I spent quite a lot of time learning how to use QEMU the hard way -- using command line. Invoking `savevm` on the QEMU monitor console save the states of the VM just fine, although it saves the CPU and RAM states on the first writable disk (usually the pflash variable store).