# Error creating snapshot: Operation not supported: internal snapshots of a VM with pflash based firmware are not supported

Tags: arch-linux, libvirt, snapshot, virt-manager

I'm using Arch Linux, both host and guest. For UEFI boot, I've installed `edk2-ovmf` and made the guest use the firmware `/usr/share/edk2-ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd`. I want to create snapshots of my VM but am getting the error:

```
Error creating snapshot: Operation not supported: internal snapshots of a VM with pflash based firmware are not supported

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 65, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/details/snapshots.py", line 237, in _do_create_snapshot
    self.vm.create_snapshot(xml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1124, in create_snapshot
    self._backend.snapshotCreateXML(xml, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 3059, in snapshotCreateXML
    raise libvirtError('virDomainSnapshotCreateXML() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: Operation not supported: internal snapshots of a VM with pflash based firmware are not supported
```

It seems my choice of firmware, which was required to use UEFI boot which was required to install Arch, doesn't support snapshots?

Is there a way I can create snapshots with my current setup?

Answer (score 14):

There is no fix for internal snapshots even in year 2022.  The only solution would be to use external snapshots.  For more details visit [KVM: creating and reverting libvirt external snapshots](https://fabianlee.org/2021/01/10/kvm-creating-and-reverting-libvirt-external-snapshots/).  All the credits for the external snapshots examples go to [Fabien Lee](https://fabianlee.org/).

## External snapshot for simple guest domains

### Creating external snapshot

If your guest domain is a simple VM where all the `<disk>` are of  `type="file"`, then creating an external snapshot of a powered-on VM’s state (excluding the RAM) looks like below.  For this example, assume there is a hard drive at `hda` and CD-ROM at `hdb`.

```
# name of domain, snapshot, and target disk device
thedomain="mysimpledomain"
snapshotname="simple-test"
targetdisk="hda"

# look at '<disk>' types, should be just 'file' types
virsh dumpxml $thedomain | grep '<disk' -A5

# show block level devices and qcow2 paths (hda,hdb,..etc)
virsh domblklist $thedomain

# create snapshot in default pool location
# file name is $thedomain.$snapshotname
virsh snapshot-create-as $thedomain --name $snapshotname --disk-only

# list snapshot
virsh snapshot-list $thedomain
```

### Reverting external snapshot

To see the mechanism underneath and prepare variables for the revert of the snapshot, execute the commands below.

```
# notice path to hda has now changed to snapshot file
virsh domblklist $thedomain

# <source> has changed to snapshot file
virsh dumpxml $thedomain | grep '<disk' -A5

# pull default pool path from xml 
pooldir=$(virsh pool-dumpxml default | grep -Po "(?<=path\>)[^<]+")
echo "default pool dir: $pooldir"

# should see two files starting with $thedomain
# the one named $thedomain.$snapshotname is the snapshot
cd $pooldir
ls -latr $thedomain*

# snapshot points to backing file, which is original disk
sudo qemu-img info $thedomain.$snapshotname -U --backing-chain

# capture original backing file name so we can revert
backingfile=$(qemu-img info $thedomain.$snapshotname -U | grep -Po 'backing file:\s\K(.*)')
echo "backing file: $backingfile"
```

To do the revert we need to modify the domain xml back to the original qcow2 file, delete the snapshot metadata, and finally the snapshot file.

```
# stop VM
virsh destroy $thedomain

# edit hda path back to original qcow2 disk
virt-xml $thedomain --edit target=$targetdisk --disk path=$backingfile --update

# validate that we are now pointing back at original qcow2 disk
virsh domblklist $thedomain

# delete snapshot metadata
virsh snapshot-delete --metadata $thedomain $snapshotname

# delete snapshot qcow2 file
sudo rm $pooldir/$thedomain.$snapshotname

# start guest domain
virsh start $thedomain
```

The guest domain should now be in the original state.  For more details about external snapshots, visit the link above.

## Why the internal snapshots have been disabled?

Why the internal snapshots have been disabled you can read below. One of thee best answer I found when searching this topis is [this](https://www.spinics.net/lists/virt-tools/msg11470.html):

> On Mon, Sep 04, 2017 at 08:30:23AM -0700, ovirt@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> wrote:
>
> > o/s: Fedora 26 + Virt-Manager v1.42
> > vm: Win 10 UEFI + Q35
> >
> > Error creating snapshot: Operation not supported:
> > Internal snapshots of a VM with pflash based firmware are not supported.
> >
> > Is there a fix?
>
> Hi, unfortunately no, and it will probably take some time to support
> snapshots for guests with UEFI.
>
> The issue is that internal snapshots are obsolete and misses a lot of
> features that external snapshots have.  They are basically usable only
> for guests with only one disk, where everything including the guest
> state is stored in one file.
>
> In order to get this fixed and to get snapshots for guests with UEFI
> virt-manager will have to switch to use external snapshots, there is
> already a BUG for it [3](https://www.spinics.net/lists/virt-tools/msg11470.html).  However, it cannot be currently done
> because libvirt still lacks some mandatory features for external
> snapshots, for example you cannot revert to external snapshot which
> makes them unusable.  There is also a BUG for libvirt to implement
> this [4](https://listman.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2017-March/msg01087.html).
>
> Pavel
>
> [3](https://www.spinics.net/lists/virt-tools/msg11470.html) https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1403951 [4](https://listman.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2017-March/msg01087.html)
> https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1402581

The reason for this is [here](https://listman.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2017-March/msg01087.html):

> Re: [libvirt] [PATCH v2] qemu: snapshot: Forbid internal snapshots
> with pflash firmware
>
> ```
> From: Laszlo Ersek <lersek redhat com>
> To: Peter Krempa <pkrempa redhat com>
> Cc: libvir-list redhat com
> Subject: Re: [libvirt] [PATCH v2] qemu: snapshot: Forbid internal snapshots with pflash firmware
> Date: Thu, 23 Mar 2017 17:49:56 +0100
> ```
>
> On 03/23/17 15:07, Peter Krempa wrote:
>
> > On Thu, Mar 23, 2017 at 11:03:02 +0100, Laszlo Ersek wrote:
> >
> > > On 03/23/17 10:54, Peter Krempa wrote:
> > >
> > > > On Thu, Mar 23, 2017 at 10:48:01 +0100, Laszlo Ersek wrote:
> > > >
> > > > > On 03/23/17 10:29, Peter Krempa wrote:
> > > > >
> > > > > > If the variable store () file is raw qemu can't do a snapshot of
> > > > > > it and thus the snapshot would be incomplete. QEMU does no reject such
> > > > > > snapshot.
> > > > > >
> > > > > > Additionally allowing to use a qcow2 variable store backing file would
> > > > > > solve this issue but then it would become eligible to become target of
> > > > > > the memory dump.
> > > > > >
> > > > > > Offline internal snapshot would be incomplete too with either storage
> > > > > > format since libvirt does not handle the pflash file in this case.
> > > > > >
> > > > > > Forbid such snapshot so that we can avoid problems.
> >
> > [...]
> >
> > > > @@ -13873,8 +13873,14 @@ qemuDomainSnapshotPrepare(virConnectPtr conn,
> > > > goto cleanup;
> > > > }
> > > >
> > > > - /* Internal snapshots don't work with VMs with OVMF loader since qemu does
> > > > - ```
> > > >   * not snapshot the variable store */
> > > >   ```
> > > >
> > > > - /* internal snapshots + pflash based loader have the following problems:
> > > > - ```
> > > >   * - if the variable store is raw, the snapshot is incomplete
> > > >   ```
> > > > - ```
> > > >   * - alowing a qcow2 image as the varstore would make it eligible to receive
> > > >   ```
> > > > - ```
> > > >   *   the vmstate dump, which would make it huge
> > > >   ```
> > > > - ```
> > > >   * - offline snapshot would not snapshot the varstore at all
> > > >   ```
> > > > - ```
> > > >   *
> > > >   ```
> > > > - ```
> > > >   * Avoid the issues by forbidding this completely.
> > > >   ```
> > > > - ```
> > > >   */
> > > >   ```
> >
> > I thought about this a bit more and I think that while there are the
> > above problems we still can have users of snapshots + OVMF which use it
> > successfully. Forbiding it would create a regression for them since they
> > did not observe anything bad despite the problems mentioned above:
> >
> > The reasons are following:
> >
> > 1. internal snapshots are the default in virt-manager
> > 2. guests usually don't re-write the varstore very often, usually only
> >    at install
> > 3. OSes usually don't modify anything besides the boot entry
> > 4. snapshot of an online VM carries the varstore in the memory image
> > 5. OSes are pretty good at restoring the boot entry if it fails
> >
> > Due to the facts above I think that there are users that legitimately
> > think that snapshots with pflash loaders work as expected. It's mostly
> > due to the fact that the data are pretty static and OSes don't store
> > anything important there and are able to self-heal some of the problems.
> >
> > I think we should not disallow this to avoid usability regressions. We
> > can add documentation that states that it's unsafe to do snapshots.
> > Additionally we will need to add support for external snapshots, which
> > currently have similar kind of problems, although fixable.
>
> The tradeoff is between a seemingly working, but inherently unsafe
> operation, and a clear error message that keeps things safe.
>
> The UEFI variable store is used for more and different things than you
> mention, such as (in roughly decreasing order of importance):
>
> - Some UEFI variables (the authenticated ones) have security impact. This covers the standardized ones used for Secure Boot (Platform Key,
>   Key Exchange Keys, white-listed certificates and signatures (DB) and
>   black-listed certificates and signatures (DBX)).
> - To my knowledge, it also includes some similar security-related variables used by shim / MokManager (where "MOK" is short for Machine
>   Owner Key); that is, non-volatile variables to which shim delegates
>   the EFI binaries' verification, from the standardized Secure Boot
>   interfaces.
> - UEFI variables can serve as the backend for the linux "pstore" (persistent store) file system. Pstore in turn can be used to save the
>   last part of dmesg on a crash. The messages can be re-read at a new
>   boot.
> - Firmware uses (reads/writes) a number of variables internally at each boot. These may not be critical. One example is a variable that
>   helps reduce UEFI memory map fragmentation over a series of boots.
> - OVMF manipulates UEFI boot options on each boot, according to the bootindex properties (or more directly, according to the "bootorder"
>   fw_cfg file). Although, admittedly, this is likely the least risky
>   category of varstore contents.
>
> While I have myself successfully used -- offline only -- internal
> snapshots with OVMF guests, hand-waving away the knowledge that the
> varstore was never actually snapshotted, I feel real uncomfortable
> about silently performing an inherently lossy operation, especially
> when the varstore may well have security impact.
>
> Users will not read the documentation (they never do), and I would
> rather not field future bug reports about obscure Secure Boot
> misbehavior.
>
> It is ultimately up to libvirt developers, but IMO, if we continue to
> allow this unsafe operation, then the minimum would be:
>
> - in virt-manager, pop up an extra confirmation dialog, with clear indication that the operation will be lossy and could have security
>   impact,
> - in virsh, reject the operation with a similar error message, unless "--force" or something similar were specified.
> - And, because there are other (independent) libvirt client applications, this would likely require a new flag on the libvirt API
>   level, so that libvirt itself can reject unsafe snapshotting requests,
>   regardless of the client application that submits it.
>
> I agree that usability regressions are not nice and will likely
> generate bug reports; however, *if* they are in direct conflict with
> security improvements, then security improvements trump usability
> regressions. I guess we can allow users to ignore security, but they
> need to be informed on the spot, and they have to opt in.
>
> I would prefer if we went ahead with this patch; but, again, it's up
> to you in the end.
>
> Thanks! Laszlo